# Pojo to json with validations

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following class

```
public class Person {
   public String id;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String gender;
    public String profession;
```

I have list of person List listPerson. I need to convert this to JSON but i need to implement some validations like firstname size should be greater than 3 ,id should not be null.

I am able to convert the listPerson to JSON string but not able to implement validations.How can i implement the validations ?

I am using Spring boot  latest version with java 8.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(listPerson);
        stem.out.println(jsonInString);
```

Comment: Why should the the JSON converter be doing validation? You could just check the object before you convert it (convertion will not change your data)

Answer (score 0):

For validate field you need to use javax validation annotation like `@NotNull, @Size, @NotBlank` etc.

```
public class Person {

    @NotBlank
    public String id;
    @Size(min = 4)
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String gender;
    public String profession;
}
```

To call manual validatoin u need to autowire `Validator`

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
```

Now u can call `validate` function

```
    validator.validate(personObject);
```

Comment: how to write manual validation and add it.    @Size(min = 4)
 is not working in my code

Comment: check what do u import. import javax validation

Comment: im importing correct.

i did this
validator.validate(listPerson);

Comment: Field validator in com.rahul.kafkaproducer.producer.Csv required a bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: did u inject Validator bean?

Comment: u can autowire bean in `@Service`, `@Component` annotated class

Comment: List<Person> listPerson = personIter.readAll();

  for (Person p : listPerson) {

   System.out.println(p.firstName);
  }

Comment: @JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "firstName","lastName", "email", "profession" })
public class Person {

 
 
    public String id;
    @Size(min = 7)
 public String firstName;

Comment: what next to do .i dont understand your point.i am getting even those objects whose firstName size is less than 7

Comment: Try the following which should construct your validator:
`ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();`